# dlls on windows and dylibs on macintosh

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, bundle, dylib

I have joined a project that has been written in xcode using objective-C that is using some frameworks. This project is aimed at adding Wii-mote functionality to both the windows and Macintosh versions of Unity3d.

My question is how should I go about getting a windows dll that mirrors the functionality of the Macintosh .bundle/.dylib?

Do I need to start translating the code from Objective-C to C#?
or,
Do I need to find/code my own windows .dll from scratch?
or,
Is there a library type that is compatible with both windows and Macintosh?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is not a library type that is compatible with both systems.  It might be possible to use C# libraries on both systems if you're using Mono on the Mac to run C# code, but you already stated that it's an Objective-C project, so I'm guessing that option is out.

So yes, you'll need to write your own .dll on the Windows side in your language of choice.

Comment: You may want to explain to the OP why that is, on the more basic levels (assembly, architectures, etc.)